# How to change an entire website's files' character encoding to UTF-8?

Tags: character-encoding, character

How can I change all of my php/css/js files to utf character encoding? I can't get it to validate otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the .htaccess option "AddCharset". It should work on the parent directory of where the .htaccess file is located plus all sub directories.

```
AddCharset UTF-8 .php
```

[http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-htaccess-charset](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-htaccess-charset#extension)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said what encoding the files are in at the moment, or what operating system you are using. On my Ubuntu system, I have a command called `iconv` that will convert a single file. Using this, I would write a simple script to convert files "in-place". For example, to convert from iso8859-15 to utf-8, put this script in `/tmp/convert`:

```
#!/bin/sh
iconv -f iso8859-15 -t utf-8 "$1" > "$1.$$" && mv "$1.$$" "$1"
```

then run:

```
chmod 755 /tmp/convert
```

and then run `find` to execute that script on all `.php`, `.js` and `.css` files:

```
find /my/website/root -name \*.php -o -name \*.js -o -name \*.css -exec /tmp/convert {} \;
```

Remember to back up your files first in case the conversion doesn't do what you expect.