# how to prevent server I don't own from sending charset=UTF-8 in the http request

Tags: html, http, character-encoding

I have an old web site in French tha I want to preserve and whose html files were encoded in iso-8859-1. All html files included

```
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
```

in the <head> element, however the host of my website changed something in the configuration an now pages are sent from their server with an HTTP header including

```
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

and unfortunately someone decided this would override the <meta> information.

Do I have to trans-code all my html files to UTF-8 or is there a faster solution?

---

**Update**

In fact the charset was added to the http header's content-type field *only* for html content issued by php, not for pure html files. I'll put the solution I adopted as an answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675073/how-to-change-an-entire-websites-files-character-encoding-to-utf-8

Comment: @mplungjan thanks, that would be the first option in Quentin 's answer

Comment: @mplungjan in fact the link you provided also has another solution that is close to what I want, using .htaccess. The problem is: There are a few recent files that are in UTF-8.

Comment: It was the second one I was posting it for since you already had problems with how they set the headers

Comment: So grep for é and ignore those

Comment: I tried with .htaccess but it seems RemoveCharset and RemoveType instructions are ignored.

Comment: Hey, got it wrong, I'll update my question and add its own answer.\

Answer (score 0):

Your options:

- Transcode the files
- Persuade whomever changed the server configuration to change it again
- Change servers
- Run all every request through a server side script which outputs a different Content-Type header and then outputs the HTML (which accounting for cache-control headers)

Comment: Thanks. Can you develop on the 4th option?

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while to realize the problem occurs only for .php files. The fix I chose is the following: I added the line

```
ini_set('default_charset', NULL);
```

at the beginning of every php files. A bit tedious but seems reasonable to me.